# How to enable mobile optimized signin with Twilio?

Tags: android, twilio

I'm developing some mobile apps integrated with Twilio.

followed the practices & twilio docs from [**this link**](https://www.twilio.com/docs/connect)
Functionally, the whole flow is implemented and verified!
However, trying to solve a representational problem ***on mobile web*** using Twilio Connect

Here are the steps I implemented on Android;

1. connect with Facebook (mainly to hide twilio connect behing
   proper auth)
2. launch WebView to
   https://www.twilio.com/authorize/CN51ffbdb77fb055eb1dd3eb2858f711b7/signin

*p.s. twilio_connect_app_sid is assigned as reference app: CN51ffbdb77fb055eb1dd3eb2858f711b7*

The problem is; 
the displayed signin/signup page (in step.2) is NOT mobile friendly, it just overflow the screen! deff not user-friendly way to ask user to signin/signup...
Even on some of the Android phones (and emulator), SignIn page is not displayed properly, user+pass section is completely broken..!

Is there any way to pass parameter like display=touch  as we do for facebook auth?
Simply, looking for a way to display Twilio SignIn/SignUp page in mobile-optimised way.

additionally; just added impl of Twilio Connect on one of my open source projects see prj [@github](https://github.com/wareninja/generic-oauth2-login-for-android)

Any suggestions/comments/help?
**Btw. Anyone from Twilio in SO please???**
*basic fact; multi-screen services should be responsive/mobile-optimised by default...*

---

While discussing this issue with Twilio support, I'll try to keep this item up2date.
Why? I believe that we should share our findings & knowledge with the community..!

---

rationale:
To be able to implement this flow on native clients (Android in our case), we use WebView as the wrapper. The same applies even for Facebook like SNs, thereby also to Twilio Connect flow..!

facts:
Long story short, I took screenshots of PoC using Android Emulator..!
Steps for Auth/Connect impl for Android client can be seen [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/urriett20zk5mxk/jpRfZef2rB)

Please notice the broken page on step2-1...
You can easily reproduce this with those steps with emulator or any Android phone. Just open browser and go to twilio connect link as noted way above...

Comment: of course 404! because 'real connect appsid' is required... reading the question before clicking may help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately we don't have an ETA for a fix at the moment but we are aware of the issue.